# What does the `!` before variable in shell mean?

Tags: shell, variables

I see in a shell file, it has such code:

```
getValue ${!value}
```

You can see there is a `!` before the varaible `value`. I can't find document for this usage, what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` is used to dereference a variable, see example below:

```
abc=def
value=abc
echo ${!value}
def
```

See also [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: So in other words this is a safer/slicker way of doing `eval echo \$$value`.